# can't pass parameters react native 5.x

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

i don't know why but the program stats.js can't read the parameter passed by SearchScreen.js
Can anyone help me?

**SearchScreen.js**

```
const SearchScreen =({navigation}) => {
const [name, SetName] = React.useState();
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputText}
                    placeholder="Name of the restaurant..."
                    placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
                    onChangeText={text => SetName(text)}
                    //onSubmitEditing={ () => this.state.navigate('InsertEmailAddress', name)}
                    />
                    <Text> {name} </Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                   onPress={() => {navigation.setParams(name), navigation.navigate('Stats', name)}}>
                  <Text >continue</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
};
```

**Stats.js**

```
const StatsScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text> Stats Screen </Text>
              <Text>{route.params}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
navigation.navigate('Stats',{name});
```

Try initiating with default value:

```
const [name, SetName] = React.useState("");
```

Comment: Same result as before, the parameter is not showing :(

Comment: Don't use "navigation.setParams(name)" just use "navigation.navigate('Stats',{name: name});"

Comment: React Navigation 5.x route params https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Comment: even if I write: _onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Stats',{name: name})}_  the parameter still is not showing

Comment: what's in the "name" param contains? is it undefined? what's showing <Text>{route.params}</Text> ?

Comment: in the "name" there is the State, defined in this way: _const [name, SetName] = React.useState();_  About **<Text>{route.params}</Text>** nothing is shown.

Comment: Try initiating with a default value like const [name, SetName] = React.useState("");

Comment: The state gets updated but the parameter won't be passed and so will not be shown , so is like before. - Could you eventually help me for example using teamviewer?

Comment: Have you tried sending any other value like {param:"123"} either is receiving or not, please check

Comment: still nothing shows up :( is there a way where you could help me more direct like through teamviewer ? Sadly i can't chat you here because I have too few experience points...

Answer (score 0):

if you designed a stack navigator with routes like this

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="SearchScreen" component={SearchScreen} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Stats" component={StatsScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

This will get the params from the first screen to the second screen. if both screens fall under the same stack

```
const SearchScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [name, SetName] = React.useState('');
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        value={name}
        style={styles.inputText}
        placeholder="Name of the restaurant..."
        placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
        onChangeText={(text) => SetName(text)}
        //onSubmitEditing={ () => this.state.navigate('InsertEmailAddress', name)}
      />
      <Text> {name} </Text>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('Stats', name);
        }}>
        <Text>continue</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

```
const StatsScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text> Stats Screen </Text>
      <Text>{route.params}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

In case if you have a nested navigator there is a [slight difference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#passing-params-to-nested-navigators) in passing params rest everything remains the same.

Comment: It shouldn't be a nested navigator.
_ <Tab.Navigator
     if (route.name === 'TabA') {
   } else if (route.name === 'TabB') {
   } else if (route.name === 'TabC') {
   } else if (route.name === 'TabD') {
   } 
  ...
  <Tab.Screen name="TabA" component={Search} />
        <Tab.Screen name="TabB" component={Goal} />
        <Tab.Screen name="TabC" component={Contact}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="TabD" component={Stats} />

    </Tab.Navigator> _